# How to save data to Magento2 database?

Tags: magento2, database

I am trying to save form submitted details to database in magento2 but it is not working. i have tried different options that given by stackoverflow answers but none of them works for me.
my controller file is given below

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Suyati\Scontact\Controller\Index;

class Post extends \Suyati\Scontact\Controller\Index
{
    /**
     * Post user question
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if (!$post) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        try {
            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObject->setData($post);

            $error = false;

            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if ($error) {
                throw new \Exception();
            }

            /*$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

            $Format = $objectManager->create('Suyati\Scontact\Model\Contacts');
            $Format->setName(trim($post['name'])); 
            $Format->setEmail(trim($post['Email']));
            $Format->save();*/

            $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Suyati\Scontact\Model\Contacts');
            $model->setData($post);
            $model->save();
            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeScope))
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE,
                        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER, $storeScope))
                ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
            );
            $this->_redirect('scontact/index');
            return;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addError(
                __('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.')
            );
            $this->_redirect('scontact/index');
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Resource model

```
<?php

namespace Suyati\Scontact\Model\Resource;

class Contacts extends \Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\AbstractDb
{
public function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('suyati_contacts', 'contacts_id');
}
}
```

Resource collection

```
<?php


namespace Suyati\Scontact\Model\Resource\Contacts;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
public function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('Suyati\Scontact\Model\Contacts', 'Suyati\Scontact\Model\Resource\Contacts');
}
}
```

Comment: Your controller should extend  "\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action". Assume you are trying to post from front-end.

Comment: yes i a doing a post from front end, how can i do that? extend "\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action"

Comment: The correct method to retrieve post data as an array is $this->getRequest()->getParams().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your are using front-end, you need to extend the Front controller with

`\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`

Model extend `\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel`

Resource Model extend `\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb`

Collection extend `\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection`

Follow the working reference code and check your post data carefully.

```
class Post extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context

    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }   
    public function execute()
    {
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();       
$question = $objectManager->create('Suyati\Scontact\Model\Contacts');
$question->setData($data);
//$question->setEmail('test@test.com');
//$question->setQuery('Question Description');
$question->save();
$this->messageManager->addSuccess( __('Thanks for your valuable feedback.') );
//$this->messageManager->addSuccess('Query subbmitted successfully.');
$this->_redirect('*/*/');
return;



    }
}
```

Use constructor instead of Object Manager to create instances.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Class Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\AbstractResource does not exist

Comment: @ Naveen your resource model should extend \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb

Comment: updated my question with resource model

Comment: @Naveen Check my answer , Modify the model classes as mentioned in the answer, Remove cache and try. Good to go with for reference http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2016/04/04/magento2-crud-module-development-series-part3/

Comment: yes, i couldn't figure this out

Comment: yes  i have done this also, the same error is showing

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\AbstractDb' not found in /var/www/m2ce/app/code/Suyati/Scontact/Model/Resource/Contacts.php on line 8

Comment: @Naveen You still using existing (Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\AbstractDb) classes, change resource model (should extend \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb)as i mentioned in the answer

Comment: Practice or check http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2016/04/04/magento2-crud-module-development-series-part3/

Comment: finally done it Thankyou Krishna

Comment: Can anyone help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/214039/how-to-send-data-from-custom-fields-to-a-function-in-admin-customer-edit/214053?noredirect=1#comment298055_214053

Answer (score 0):

which table you are trying to update?
what error you are getting?

A simple custom table update can be done as below:

```
$modelObj = $this->_objectManager->create("yournamespace\yourmodulename\Model\yourdbmodelfile");

$modelObj->setYourFieldName(yourValue);
try
        {
            $modelObj->save();
        }
        catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) 
        {
            echo $e->message;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Resource model

```
<?php

namespace Suyati\Scontact\Model\Resource;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class Contacts extends AbstractDb
{
    /**
     * Define main table
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('suyati_contacts', 'contacts_id');
    }
}
```

Resource collection

```
<?php

namespace Suyati\Scontact\Model\Resource\Contacts;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Define model & resource model
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            'Suyati\Scontact\Model\Contacts',
            'Suyati\Scontact\Model\Resource\Contacts'
        );
    }
}
```

in the controller file i have called

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$Format = $objectManager->create('Suyati\Scontact\Model\Contacts');

$Format->setData($post);

$Format->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Moazzam\ManageModels\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException;
use Moazzam\ManageModels\Model\PetFactory;
use Moazzam\ManageModels\Model\ResourceModel\Pet as ResourceModelPet;

/**
 * update the db column through model
 *
 * Class Index
 */
class Save implements HttpGetActionInterface, HttpPostActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var PetFactory
     */
    private PetFactory $petFactory;

    /**
     * @var ResourceModelPet
     */
    private ResourceModelPet $resourceModelPet;
    /**
     * @var JsonFactory
     */
    private JsonFactory $jsonFactory;

    /**
     * @param PetFactory $petFactory
     * @param ResourceModelPet $resourceModelPet
     * @param JsonFactory $jsonFactory
     */
    public function __construct(PetFactory $petFactory, ResourceModelPet $resourceModelPet, JsonFactory $jsonFactory)
    {
        $this->petFactory=$petFactory;
        $this->resourceModelPet=$resourceModelPet;
        $this->jsonFactory=$jsonFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return ResponseInterface|Json|ResultInterface|void
     * @throws AlreadyExistsException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $id = 5;
        if ($id) {
            $petModel = $this->petFactory->create();
            $this->resourceModelPet->load($petModel, $id);
            $petModel->setData('pet_name', 'poodle');
            $this->resourceModelPet->save($petModel);
            $result = $this->jsonFactory->create();
            $result->setData(['success' => true]);
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```