# How can I send form data to database using magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, database

I created a menu in magento 2 admin panel, there is a form in it. below u can see that phtml file

```
<p>Test Backend Module!</p><br>

<script language="JavaScript">
function showInput() {
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
                document.getElementById("input").value;
}

</script>

<form method="POST">
    <label>Enter Your Name : </label>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="input">
</form>
<br><input type="submit" onclick="showInput();"><br>
<br><label>Your Name : </label>
<br><p><b><span id='display'></span></b></p></br>
```

If I click submit button i need to send those data to database and save in a table. how can i do that

My module directory like below

```
Company
    `-- AdminPage
        |
        |-- Controller
        |   |-- Adminhtml
        |       |-- HelloWorld
        |           `-- Index.php
        |-- etc
        |   |-- adminhtml
        |   |   |-- menu.xml
        |   |   `-- routes.xml
        |   `-- module.xml
        |-- view
        |   |-- adminhtml
        |       |-- layout
        |       |    `-- adminpage_helloworld_index.xml
        |       `-- templates
        |           `-- helloworld.phtml
        |-- composer.json
        `-- registration.php
```

Comment: Use link to solve your task    https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126305/how-to-save-data-to-magento2-database

Comment: I have my form in admin panel. not in fron end and Im new to  magento

Comment: It is same if U have form in admin also,You have to create controller on form submit controller will be called and save it to database @Hemal

Comment: Im really new to those stuff can u tell me root directories and what are the things that need to include